# Pandas compute features diff within group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with `n` rows for each group ID, where only one label is 1 and all the others are 0s.
Example:

```
ID, Feature_1; Feature_2; Feature_3; label
1,  10,        3,         4,          1
1,   9,        1,         2,          0
...
2,  100,        30,         40,          1
2,   90,        10,         20,          0
```

I want to group by ID and for each ID group transform the features for each label=0 as a diff(Feature_1_i - Feature_1_j) where i is the row with lablel=1 within the group and j to n are the other rows in the group with label=1.

Expected output

```
ID, Feature_1; Feature_2; Feature_3; label
1,  10,        3,         4,          1
1,  10 - 9,    3- 1,      4- 2,       0
...
2,  100,        30,         40,       1
2,  100-90,    30-10,      40-20,     0
```

How can I achieve this in Pandas?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What do you expect the output to look like, given the sample input shown?  Do you want the output to appear as a new df with columns for label and each Feature in which each label contains the result or something else?

Comment: @itprorh66 I have added an expected output example. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your dataframe using `sort_values` based on 'ID' and 'label in `ascending` and `descending` order respectively.

Then you can calculate a grouped difference using `diff` on your columns, which would calculate the difference between the last and first row of each group (last - new) and populate the last row, leaving the first row with `NaN`.

The last thing to do is to fill those resulted `NaN` (which are the first rows of each group):

```
df_sorted = df.sort_values(by=['ID','label'],ascending=[True,False])
df_sorted.groupby('ID').diff().assign(label=np.nan).fillna(df_sorted).astype(int)
```

prints:

```
   Feature_1;  Feature_2;  Feature_3;  label
0          10           3           4      1
1          -1          -2          -2      0
2         100          30          40      1
3         -10         -20         -20      0
```